# Pywinauto: menu_select only works once with an application

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pywinauto

I am writing a automatic test in python. To do so, I have to open and close windows from an item in a toolbar. Its name is "Tables" and has more than twenty subitems.
The code works fine with any of those subitems. But when I want to open a second one, I got an error:

*File "D:\FromSamina\TCX3_POC\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py",
line 723, in menu_select

File "D:\FromSamina\TCX3_POC\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uia_controls.py",
line 1060, in item_by_path

File "D:\FromSamina\TCX3_POC\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py",
line 375, in wait_until*

I have tried my code with notepad instead of my application with the item "Edit" to open the windows "Search" and "Replace" and it worked fine. I first wrote it in a loop. I worked the past hours on the following lines but it did not work:

```
    mexp    = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=r"E:\TOTO\TATAT\TITI.exe")
    mexp_fen_princ  = mexp.window(title_re = '.*MANON - MAINTENANCE.*')


    print("Ouverture Groupes et initialisation fenêtre fille")
    FenConsul   = mexp_fen_princ.child_window(title_re =".*Groupes.*", control_type = "Window")

    ##Open the Window "Groupes" from Tables
    mexp_fen_princ.menu_select("Tables -> Groupes")

    ##Close the window "Groupes"
    FenConsul.Annuler.click()

    ##Open table "Attributaires"
    print("Ouverture attributaires et initialisation fenêtre fille")
    mexp_fen_princ.menu_select("Tables -> Attributaires")

    FenConsul   = mexp_fen_princ.child_window(title_re =".*Attributaires.*", control_type = "Window")
    FenConsul.Annuler.click()

    time.sleep(3)
```

There is nothing special in those lines. They work with notepad but not with my tested application. I can open every sub window of the menu Tables if they are opened first. But I cannot go further. There is an exception at this line:

```
mexp_fen_princ.menu_select("Tables -> Attributaires")
```

Comment: Hello. More news.
If I still cannot open/close all the windows one at the time from the "Tables" menu, I can manage to open/close them if I include an input line such as :
input("Write any text")

If I close the window and I put the previous command right after, the next opening operation will work.
How i that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Or more precisely, found a way to avoid it.
I simulate keyboards inputs after taking the focus on the cmd before a window opening:

```
ancienstdin = sys.stdin
sys.stdin   = StringIO("9\n8\n7\n6\n)

assert.input() == "9"
assert.input() == "8"

sys.stdin  = ancienstdin
```

I still do not understand why I have to do this but it works.